# Need a query to count number of times a customer visits each region

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have a table that has an Account_Number field and a Region field, so it looks something like this:

```
Account_Number ... Region
 12345678          Region1
 12345667          Region2
```

I need to count the number of times an account number visits each region, so that the output is something like:

```
Account_Number ... Nbr_Visits ... Region
 12345678             3          Region 4
 45678923             6          Region 2
```

So, the account number can occur multiple times if that customer visits different regions in the same month. This isn't really the way I would have set it up, but a 3rd party is requiring this format and I'm not sure the best way to go about it. I'm using MS Access 2010.

Comment: The query builder (Design View)  in Access is very good for this purpose. Once you have set up the correct design (based on the right output), then you can see the SQL generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Account_Number,Region,COUNT(*) AS Nbr_Visits
FROM myTable  
GROUP BY Account_Number,Region
```

Comment: Perfect! I don't know why I had it all twisted in my head that there was more to it, but this was very simple and effective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT Account_Number, COUNT(*) AS Nbr_Visits, Region
FROM myTable
WHERE Account_Date between **date1 goes here** and **date2 goes here**
Group by Account_Number, Region
```

I added the date logic so that you can pull records back between a certain time frame. I think  in this case you stated a month. This should be a good sample to get you going.

Comment: You forget the FROM :)

Comment: exactly what i was looking for `WHERE Account_Date between **date1 goes here** and **date2 goes here**`